# Angular 2: Removing Query Parameters from URL

Tags: angular, parameters, navigation

After authenticating a user I want to remove the token from the current URL using angular's built in libraries instead of using string manipulation. Is there a way that I can remove this query specific parameter without reloading the page or removing other query parameters that might be on the path?

As an example: 
`http://somewebpage.com?token=564655324` 
although I just want the user to see the following in the address bar:
`http://somewebpage.com` or `http://somewebpage.com?query=web`

Comment: you can use `window.history.replaceState()` to rewrite the current address - but I'd advise you take a step back and evaluate your authentication mechanism if you're sending it as part of the URL

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that Angular 2 currently lacks the ability to remove a single query parameter from the subscribed queryParams observable. The solution thus was to capture the url with an interceptor, do string manipulation to remove the query parameter and then reconstruct the url. Then just set the `window.location.href` to the newly constructed URL (with the query param removed)